# Redirect all api calls on Http to Https in Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, https, gunicorn

I am running a Django app and deployed it on server using Gunicorn and Nginx. It was running on Http for a year. Now I changed it to Https using "letsencrypt". Here is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    server_name my_project.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/my_project/my_project/;
    }

    location / {
       proxy_pass_header Server;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
       proxy_connect_timeout 10;
       proxy_read_timeout 10;
       proxy_pass      http://localhost:8000;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_project.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_project.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my_project.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name my_project.com;  
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This configuration works fine when I open project page in browser i.e. it redirects me to https page. But none of my Api calls work. I got error that method not found. Kindly guide me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you define "none of my Api calls work"? It is likely that the clients using your API still make calls over HTTP and thus receive a 301 response but do not follow the redirection. Many HTTP client do not follow redirects by default.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard it is correct. When I make Api call to HTTP server, I do not get redirected to Https server and got error "Method not allowed".

Comment: Can you check in your logs if the HTTP requests reach your Django application or if this is Nginx that returns the 405 status code?

Comment: The thing which I noted that request is reaching server but Post method is converting to GET. When I used 307 instead of 301, i did not get any response even after waiting for 5 minutes.